# Access controle realization

Tags: ruby

I implement ACL for my ROR app. I have `access` variable that stores rights for users.
 
It contain hashes with array value for each user.
First array element is controller name and second element - array with action's names.

```
access = {
           'user' => [
             ['drivers', ['show','delete','update']],
             ['index',   ['edit','destroy','view']]
           ],

           'administrator' => [
             ['users', ['show','edit','delete']],
             ['index', ['delete','index','show']]
           ]
         }
```

I want to check if user have access to particular controller and action

```
user       = 'administrator'
controller = 'index'
action     = 'delete'
```

I do it with

```
if access[user]
  access[user].each do |acc|
    if acc[0].include? controller 
      if acc[1].include? action
        puts "User '#{user}' have access to controller '#{controller}' and action '#{action}'"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe exists more elegant way to store similar data or better way to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rolling it yourself, I would recommend a system like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [Stonewall](https://github.com/bokmann/stonewall).

Both of those have methods that allow you to ask "Can this user do this thing on this object?".

Stonewall + [StonewallActionProtection](https://github.com/rwilcox/stonewall_action_protection), a plugin of my own, can make access checks for CRUD operations automatic.

Comment: Yeah, i know about CanCan, but i don't like that it stores permissions in database. I like _Zend Framework ACL_ way, that define all roles, resources and permissions in single file. Also it is my study project, so i want to implement it myself. Nevertheless thanks for your answer, i'll remember it whan will choose authorization gem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more elegant way : https://github.com/ezmobius/acl_system2

Comment: Thanks, i will use it as base of my own gem. But question about realization, not about the choice.